# Renaming Resource in CloudFormation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Can you rename a resource in a CloudFormation template?

Let's say I've created a stack template that creates a single lambda function.

```
GetTheFunnyPhraseText:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    CodeUri: ../Lambda/
    Handler: GetFunnyPhrase.handler
    FunctionName: GetFunnyPhrase
    Role: !GetAtt [ ExecuteFunctionGetFunnyPhrase, Arn ]
```

For whatever reason, I want to change the resource name `GetTheFunnyPhraseText` to `GetFunnyPhrase`. Is there a mechanism to change the name?

A couple things I tried...

- Changing the resource name in the template. It looks like this acts like a delete on `GetTheFunnyPhraseText` and create of `GetFunnyPhrase`. Problem here is the resource creation happens before the resource deletion causing the action to fail because the Lambda function exists.
- Create two drafts of the template. Draft-1: Change the function name for the existing resource(s). Draft-2: Delete the old resource (omit their definition from the template) and add the new resource. Execute the draft templates in sequence: 1st then 2nd. This works. It's just gross.

For folks that suggest not naming the function, understood; put a pin in that piece of feedback for the moment.

Comment: I haven't seen any other method but the second method. Gross, but works. This is one reason why it's not recommended to explicitly name resources.

Comment: I hear ya. Unfortunately, I’m boxed in on the naming front. The solution had that before I joined the team.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No! Renaming a resource's logical name is not possible in Cloud Formation.

As you tested as well, CloudFormation sees it as the removal of the old resource and creation of the new one. This is so because the logical resource IDs are bound to the physical IDs of the resources by CloudFormation after creation. But for CloudFormation template language, it only recognizes the logical ID while parsing the template so any changes to that would mean the resource associated to it is going to be changed.

In some resource types though you can set the physical IDs yourself by using certain name properties which are resource-specific, for example a resource `AWS::RDS::DBInstance` may have a property `DBInstanceIdentifier` which will be the physical name of the db instance itself.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

Now that [CloudFormation import is available](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html) it's technically possible to do this, although it's tedious.

Here's what you'd need to do:

1. Update the definition for `GetTheFunnyPhraseText` to add `DeletionPolicy: "Retain"`, upload to CloudFormation
2. Remove `GetTheFunnyPhraseText` entirely from your template. Upload to CloudFormation. This will not actually delete the underlying Lambda because of the previously added `DeletionPolicy`
3. Revert your template back to the previous state in Step #1 (add `GetTheFunnyPhraseText` back) and change the logical name to `GetFunnyPhrase`
4. Start the "Stack Actions" > "Import resources into stack" workflow.
5. Upload your reverted template (with the changed logical name, still including the `DeletionPolicy`)
6. The import process will notice the new `GetFunnyPhrase` logical name and ask you what actual `FunctionName` should be mapped to that name. Provide the existing `GetFunnyPhrase` Lambda name and complete the import.
7. Finally, you can re-upload your template and remove the `DeletionPolicy`

A tedious process for sure, but technically possible if you really don't want to delete the existing resource.

Comment: Make sure to consult the docs about Resources that support import and drift detection operations: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html?icmpid=docs_cfn_console

I was getting my hopes high, to realize that e.g. codepipelines cannot be imported.